# Substitution of list/dictionary element by the index in Hy

Tags: python, substitution, hy

Is there any way to substitute a value for an element of list or dictionary by the index in Hy?
The `nth` function seems not corresponds to Python's square bracket.

I had expected like the following translation.

```
(setv lst [1 2 3])
(setv (nth lst 1) 20)

lst=[1, 2, 3]
lst[1]=20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/api.html#assoc), you have to use the `assoc` function to set a value at a specific index in a list. As such, your code should be:

```
(assoc lst 1 20)
```

This should give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `assoc`, Hy can also use `setv` on a `get` special form or on a `.` form with the `[]` syntax to set at an index or key.

```
$ hy --spy  # Shows Python translation.
[...]
=> (setv lst [1 2 3])
lst = [1, 2, 3]
None

=> (setv (. lst[1]) 20)
lst[1] = 20
None

=> lst
lst

[1, 20, 3]
=> (setv (get lst 2) 30)
lst[2] = 30
None

=> lst
lst

[1, 20, 30]
```

Of course, these operators are ultimately backed by the `__setitem__` method, which you can call like any other method.

```
=> (.__setitem__ lst 0 10)
lst.__setitem__(0, 10)

=> lst
lst

[10, 20, 30]
```

Using `__setitem__` directly is not recommended over the other aforementioned forms, but it can be useful in higher-order functions sometimes.